# Find Vector AD given points A, B, C

Tags: trigonometry, vectors

Here is an image to illustrate my issue:

[image: Illustration]

I need to calculate the vector $\vec{AD}$, knowing only the points A, B and C.

My initial idea was to calculate the angle $\alpha$ between $\vec{AB}$ and $\vec{AC}$, then calculate the last angle of the the triangle, by calculating $180 - 90 - \alpha$ and then use the arcsine of the resulting angle to get $\vec{AD}$. However I am not sure whether this is the most efficient approach, nor whether the method is error-safe.

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: Please clarify: Is $A\hat{D}C$ a square angle?

Comment: @Mefitico Yes, $\vec{DC}$ should be normal in relation to $\vec{AB}$.

Comment: Then I guess gave the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\vec{AD}$ is the orthogonal projection of $\vec {AC}$ on $\vec {AB}$ that is

$$\vec {AD}=\frac{\vec {AC}\cdot \vec {AB}}{\vec {AB}\cdot \vec {AB}}\vec {AB}$$